# An Easy Probability Calculation Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Prompt: In a game two fair dice are thrown. If the sum of the two dice is odd they are thrown once more. What is the probability that the dice in any final throw in the game show the same number? Provide your answer to two decimal places.

The answer, according to the answer key, is (around) 0.25, but I don't know how to get there.

My solution is:

Number of all cases = 18 (two dices with an even sum) + 18*6 (two dices with an odd sum, then a third dice) = 126.

Two dices are thrown and both dices show the same number = 6.

Three dices are thrown and the third shows the sum of the first two = 6. (123, 213, 145, 415, 235, 325).

Three dices are thrown and the third is the same as the first or second = 18*2 = 36.

I got several answers by interpreting the question differently. My answers are 0.05, 0.33, 0.19, 0.24. None of my answers matches the key.

Comment: Note that only throws with result $2,4,6,8,10,12$ count. So you only have to consider the cases leading to such a result. Count how many cases we have and consider that there are $6$ possibilities for having the same number twice.

Comment: Hello. Is the question really written with this exact wording? It's ambiguous and confusing, to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add up all of the cases because they do not occur with equal probability.

Let $E$ represent the event that the outcome of the first roll of the two dice has an even sum.  Let $D_i$ represent the event that the $i^{\rm th}$ roll shows the same number on each die (which we will call a "double" or "rolling a double").  Let $D$ represent the event that a double was rolled on either the first or second roll, if a second roll occurred.

Then
$$\Pr[D] = \Pr[D \mid E]\Pr[E] + \Pr[D \mid \bar E]\Pr[\bar E],$$

where $\bar E$ is the complementary event that the first roll had an odd sum.

Now, $\Pr[D \mid E] = \Pr[D_1 \mid E]$, because if the first roll was even, there is no opportunity to reroll, hence $D = D_1$.  Similarly, $\Pr[D \mid \bar E] = \Pr[D_2 \mid \bar E]$ since a double was not rolled on the first try as the sum was odd.

Next we must compute these conditional probabilities.  Given that the first roll was even, there are $18$ such outcomes, and of these, $6$ are doubles, so $$\Pr[D_1 \mid E] = \frac{1}{3}.$$  However, for $\Pr[D_2 \mid E]$, the second roll can be any of the $36$ usual outcomes, of which again $6$ are doubles, so $$\Pr[D_2 \mid E] = \frac{1}{6}.$$  And since $$\Pr[E] = \Pr[\bar E] = \frac{18}{36} = \frac{1}{2},$$ it follows that
$$\Pr[D] = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much!